# html2canvas/jsPDF - images not showing when converting html to a pdf

Tags: javascript, canvas, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm looking to convert some simple HTML into a PDF. It seems the easiest way to do this and keep the css styling is to use the 'html2canvas' js library to convert the html to canvas first, and then create the PDF using jsPDF.

The issue I'm getting is that I have both a background image and inline image in my HTML but neither are showing in the PDF once converted. I've created a Codepen here: https://codepen.io/adamboother/pen/NWGeqom

Here's my js that does the conversion:

```
function convertToPdf()
{
    html2canvas(document.querySelector('#certificate')).then(canvas => {
        let pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', 'mm', 'a4');

        pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 0, 0, pdf.internal.pageSize.width, pdf.internal.pageSize.height);

        pdf.save('certificate.pdf');
    });
}
```

Has anyone found a fix for this?

Answer (score 7):

I am using `useCORS: true` to your code and it works, assuming your image is in the server. Besides you can follow below code:

```
function convertToPdf()
{ 
    html2canvas(document.querySelector('#certificate'), {useCORS: true}).then(function(canvas) {
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      img.onload = function () {
        let pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', 'mm', 'a4');
        pdf.addImage(img, 0, 0, pdf.internal.pageSize.width, pdf.internal.pageSize.height);
        pdf.save('certificate.pdf');
      };
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, @shoma 's answer works for me. this is my code `HTML` and Image bind to the PDF

```
pdf.html(htmlContent, {
  html2canvas: { scale: 0.8 },
  pagesplit: true,
  callback: () => {
    html2canvas(SELECTOR_HERE, {
      useCORS: true
    }).then((canvas) => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      img.onload = () => {
        pdf.addImage(img, 0, 0, pdf.internal.pageSize.width, 200);
        pdf.save(`download-${genarateFileName}.pdf`);
      };
    });
  }
```

Comment: You are doing good, keep it up.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question, but a response to Shoma's answer. Please use the answer functionality only to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I couldn't resolve it. So I parsed image as `base64`. Worked like a charm, expect super long string in my code.